# Selected value in ViewBag SelectList not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set the selected value for a dropdown menu in my controller and pass it to my view via ViewBag. When I debug, all the correct values are being passed to the controller and to the view as well, but when it actually renders on the page, the selected value is not set.

View

```
<tr class="form-group">
<th>
    <label for="CompanyID" class="control-label col-md-9">Company</label>
</th>
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyID, "", new { @class = "required-validation" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyID)
</td>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id) {
if (id == null) {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
var sale = db.SalesOpportunities.Find(id);
if (sale == null) {
    return HttpNotFound();
}

ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name", sale.CompanyID);

var technicians = db.UserProfiles.Select(t => new {
    ID = t.ID,
    Name = t.FirstName + " " + t.LastName,
}).OrderBy(t => t.Name);

ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(technicians, "ID", "Name", sale.UserID);

return View(sale);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the field and the name of the variable in `ViewBag` for your choices cannot be the same. Change it from `ViewBag.CompanyID` to something like `ViewBag.CompanyChoices` and it will work.